# Print Rotation Matrix From Variable?

Tags: coordinates

So i have these variables that search for the active object's coordinates.

```
obj = bpy.context.scene.objects.active

Xrot = obj.rotation_euler.x
Yrot = obj.rotation_euler.x
Zrot = obj.rotation_euler.x

eul = mathutils.Euler((Xrot, float(Yrot), Zrot), 'XYZ') # <--- Does not print coordinates

mat_rot = eul.to_matrix() #Convert rotations to matrix

mat = mat_rot.to_4x4() #Lets turn this into a grid!

print(mat)
```

However the "eul' variable does not read out the coordinates. If I also try using float on the Xrot for Zrot variables then i will get a "too many arguments" error.

I've attempted to use "int" aswell but no luck.

Comment: SImpler to use `mat_rot = obj.rotation_euler.to_matrix()`  (assuming you dont want to set each to the x rotation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is fine, i just tested and it work as expected. The problem maybe is that you are looking in the python interactive console, but you need to look in the system console.

python interactive console after run script:

[image]

System console after run script:

[image]

If you are in GNU/Linux os look in the terminal or run blender from a terminal.

In Windows got to:  Window>Toggle System console:

[image]

```
mat_rot = eul.to_matrix() #Convert rotations to matrix

mat = mat_rot.to_4x4() #Lets turn this into a grid!

print(mat)
print(mat[0])
print(mat[0][0])
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah I did have it open but it would oddly give me the default coordinates like you have at the very top, first 4x4 one. As one comment suggested to try:    mat_rot = obj.rotation_euler.to_matrix()     which works fine now. All i need left is to figure out printing a single value from a row.

Comment: Sorry my english comprehension make me dificult to understand. but if you want a single value from ``mat_rot = obj.rotation_euler.to_matrix()`` use ``mat_rot[row][colum]`` that will give you  a single value.